# Array form insert only if the form has value in laravel

Tags: forms, laravel, insert, is-empty

I have this in my `store controller`:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
        $medicalRecord = new medicalRecord();
            $medicalRecord->patient_id = $request->input("patient_id");
             $medicalRecord->keluhan = $request->input("keluhan");
            $medicalRecord->anamnesis = $request->input("anamnesa");
            $medicalRecord->diagnosis = $request->input("diagnosa");
         $medicalRecord->save();   


        // begin problem //
        $input = Input::all();

        foreach($input['obat'] as $key => $medicalRecord_id) {
            $insert[$key]['medicalRecord_id'] = $medicalRecord->id;
        }
        foreach($input['obat'] as $key => $obat) {
            $insert[$key]['terapi'] = $obat;
        }
        foreach($input['keterangan'] as $key => $keterangan) {
            $insert[$key]['keterangan'] = $keterangan;
        }

        treatment::insert($insert);
        //end problem//


        return redirect()->back();
}
```

In blade I have forms like these:

```
<input type="text" name="obat[]"class="form-control" placeholder="Nama obat">
<input type="text" name="keterangan[]"class="form-control" placeholder="Keterangan">
```

There are 10 rows of them in blade.
Those codes inside `problem block` actually work. What make me stack is all forms are inserted into database even if they are empty. I tried changing the default value of the field in the database table but it returns error if some of the forms are empty.

How to filter those forms to proceed only the  forms with values?

Answer (score 1):

Create a [FormRequest class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation)  with validation for that route. You can prevent empty values by using the [required](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-required) or [filled](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-filled) validation rule.

Comment: I changed my forms using jquery dynamic add/remove form field to solve my problem.
thanks for your response anyway.